# What is SQL Server doing in the background once a Backup/Restore is complete?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I run a backup or restore through the SSMS GUI, the dialog shows Executing with 20% increments rather than every 1% tick. To get round this, we can use DMV's. Thing is, when the query shows 100% complete, the SSMS GUI remains for a good 5 or so minutes before the 'Restore complete' dialog appears.

Question is, what is SQL server doing during this time? Some kind of integrity check? Index rebuild? Activity monitor shows 0 R/W on the .MDF whilst the GUI dialog persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database restore process is performed in 3 steps:

1. copy -Copy data from the backup
2. redo - commit completed transactions in T-Log
3. Undo - Rollback incomplete transactions

Restore process doesn't perform any maintenance tasks like index rebuild etc.

> When I run a backup or restore through the SSMS GUI, the dialog shows
>   Executing with 20% increments rather than every 1% tick.

If you have used T-SQL statements to backup your database, you would have been aware of `STATS` parameter. It take `int` as input and prints what % of the backup have been processed.

Ex:-

If we use `STATS=5` then it'll print restore status after every 5% completion. Like

```
5%
10%
15%
..
```

Post database restore it's good practice to execute [`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I would prefer to use `PHYSICAL_ONLY`.

When a log is restored, it also takes some time to zero out the log file.  If the log file is large, [this can take several minutes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bobsql/2017/04/21/sql-server-mysteries-the-case-of-the-not-100-restore/).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server also writes additional transaction logs while you are making the backup. After restore, these transactions need to be applied, so if a lot of activity happens during your backup it can take a while to apply those operations and then rezero the log file.

One final thing, if you are still having mysteries around time you can [turn on trace flags](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/02/06/how-it-works-how-does-sql-server-backup-and-restore-select-transfer-sizes/) 3004, 3213 and 3605 before restore (don't forget to turn them off after) and all activity for the restore and associated operations will be written to the SQL Server log. I often find this helpful, when restore is "doing something" but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

[*tibor-karaszi*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi): My bet is on the `REDO` and `UNDO` phases. These aren't included in the % complete, since the amount of work is unknown in advance, and it happens after the data copying phase.